# Handle button event in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

today I have a couple of questions, I'm new in the ASP and C# so I need some help, the problem is the next. (I will try be the most specific possible)

I've created a GridView that I fill from my Database, In my GridView I added a column of buttons (Details), here goes the questions. when I click a button, I need open a new Window in the browser (How can I do this from C#, or it is possible just with javascrip? on client side)  and after I need show the details from the database, first I need to get the  ID from the row where is the button, that is the Column ID in the GridView, so how can I get the row value of the ID Column where I clicking  the button?

Here is my ASP GridView Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
AllowPaging="true" CellPadding="3"
OnPageIndexChanging="grdData_PageIndexChanging" PagerSettings-Position="Top"
PagerStyle-ForeColor="Orange"
PageSize="10">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="request_type" HeaderText="RequestType"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="priority" HeaderText="Priority" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="modality" HeaderText="Modality" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="start_date" HeaderText="Start Date"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="end_date" HeaderText="End Date"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="hour" HeaderText="Start Hour" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="requester" HeaderText="Requester Name" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Details" runat="server" 
                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" 
                Text="Details" CssClass="botonformulario"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

I try this in code behind but I think is not working.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
        //my code here.. 

    }
```

I tried do the same from this page.

http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/05/how-to-handle-click-event-of-linkbutton.html

and from this one too,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, when I click a button nothing happens. 
I've tried put breakpoints but I noticed that the breakpoint never occurs

Thanks so much for your time, any comment will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
  AutoGenerateColumns="false"
  AllowPaging="true" CellPadding="3"
  OnPageIndexChanging="grdData_PageIndexChanging" PagerSettings-Position="Top"
  PagerStyle-ForeColor="Orange"
  PageSize="10">
  <Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="request_type" HeaderText="RequestType"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="priority" HeaderText="Priority" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="modality" HeaderText="Modality" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="start_date" HeaderText="Start Date"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="end_date" HeaderText="End Date"  />
<asp:BoundField DataField="hour" HeaderText="Start Hour" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="requester" HeaderText="Requester Name" />
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Details" runat="server" 
            CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" 
            Text="Details" OnClick="Details_Click" CommandName='<%# Eval("id")%>' CssClass="botonformulario"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

```
protected void Details_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
          Button btn=(Button)sender;
          Response.Redirect("Details.aspx?id="+btn.CommandName);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `GridView1_RowCommand` handler but it not being binded in the html you posted. You probably need to bind [GridView.RowCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) the event to `GridView`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
AllowPaging="true" CellPadding="3"
OnPageIndexChanging="grdData_PageIndexChanging" PagerSettings-Position="Top"
PagerStyle-ForeColor="Orange"
PageSize="10">
```

Once you get the event fired you need to identify the source for this you would use `CommandName`

```
 <asp:Button ID="Details" runat="server" CommandName="cmdDetails"
            CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" 
            Text="Details" CssClass="botonformulario"/>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this just now :)